# Weird git diff on a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have a Laravel project on bitbucket when I did a `git clone` on my home pc, which didn't have the project, without doing any modification I did a `git status` and got this:

[image]

All my created files were modified like:

[image]

Should I push?

Comment: Did you run any tooling to get the project functional?

Comment: Ouch! My eyes!!